# Where does the saying that a match ending in a draw is like "kissing your sister" come from?

Tags: trivia, history

My father told me that saying a number of times watching rugby over the years so I thought it was a South African saying but after watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xk1Fh43Ur48&feature=youtu.be&t=4m47s) I actually heard an NZ commentator mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In US traditionally the draw is a result that does not satisfy either of the two teams.

This expression comes from Navy coach [Eddie Erdelatz in 1953](https://web.archive.org/web/20080104230142/http://listserv.linguistlist.org/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0211d&L=ads-l&D=0&P=7866), when he came up with this classic definition for a tie
football game while describing a scoreless tie between Navy and Duke.

The coach did not explain this metaphor, but it is possible to think about a kiss like a good thing (the victory), and kissing one's sister takes away the good to this gesture.

Comment: Maybe it is because you are both doing a thing but neither one is getting what they want... (-;